# Capture an event of native browser window in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

**"windows.open() - window to process login and allowing consent to fetch the documents from third-party server like any storage drive which contains files."**

now suppose I'm running angular application on http://localhost:4200/app and on the same page, opening the other browser window using windows.open(), in that same browser windows performing some task like login, accepting consent. after accepting consent the same window reloaded with redirect Uri(ex. https://testsite.com) and some parameters and window is not yet closed with an URL like https://testsite.com/app?code=12345&state=xyz

So, is it possible to extract the parameter from inner browser window and close it using angular code? is there any event that capture another windows from our application?

We have tried messageEventListener(event: MessageEvent) but no help and we tried using iframe it is not allowing to do that